# android - Update component element from @Bindable POJO property - data binding

Tags: android, observable, android-databinding, propertychanged, bindable

I am experiencing with Data Binding. I know by making my POJO (User) extending `BaseObservable` I can update the linked element in the layout by, for example using `android:text="@={user.name}"` but **I am interested in doing different staff on property changed. For example, applying some logic, or showing a toast message.** I expected was something like the `liveDataObject.observe()` method but it is not reacting when a property is changed. Here is my code:

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
  private MutableLiveData<User> user; //getter and setter
```

Model:

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {
 private String name;
 public User() {}

 @Bindable
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
  notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
 }
}
```

Fragment:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
 @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 mDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
 mDataBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
 return mDataBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(MainViewModel.class);

 mViewModel.getUser().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), user ->
  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
 );
}
```

Comment: It's not so clear what are you asking about. LiveData is like your BaseObservable but with steroids. What sense to mix them? To observe your LiveData's change (after some property changes) you have to reset your LiveData value explicitly with setValue() or postValue()

Comment: What I want is to react to property changes, not to the whole object change. If I call setValue or postValue on a liveData object, I update the whole object, but I just want to update some properties